# Backgroundimage overlaps content while scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with a fixed background image on my website. When a user scrolls the pages, the content, header and footer disappear behind the background image sometimes. After the scroll it takes a few seconds but then the content pops back up over the background. I have no clue what causes this issue and can't find any info on it. Here is the css I use:

**Background Image**

```
  .backgroundImage {
  z-index: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center 12rem;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 560px;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**Footer**

```
  footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #277ac0;
  padding: 6rem 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Post the output and JSfiddle please

Comment: Sounds like a z-index issue. ....and by background image I assume you mean **background div**

Comment: @Paulie_D  True, i mean a background div

Comment: Please post appropriate markup.